# Open Zip Files with Explorer in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, zip

My computer was just upgraded to Windows 10 and it has 7zip installed in it. I want to open zip files using Windows Explorer but can't associate them with with explorer.exe.  When I try, I get the message

```
The program you have selected cannot be associated with this file type.  Please choose another program.
```

I read a posting about someone having a similar issue with Windows 8 and the solution was making an update to an app referred to as "windows 8 manager".  Is there an equivalent Windows 10 app?  Searching for apps called manager didn't result it anything that looked right.  Any other suggestions for opening zip files with explorer.exe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize the following code by pasting it into Notepad, saving it as a `.reg` file and merging it with admin privileges to restore your default file type association:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Created by: Shawn Brink
; http://www.tenforums.com
; Tutorial: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8703-default-file-type-associations-restore-windows-10-a.html


[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ZFSendToTarget]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ZFSendToTarget]
@="CLSID\\{888DCA60-FC0A-11CF-8F0F-00C04FD7D062}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ZFSendToTarget\PersistentHandler]
@="{098f2470-bae0-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.zip]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.zip]
@="CompressedFolder"
"Content Type"="application/x-zip-compressed"
"DontCompressInPackage"=""
"PerceivedType"="compressed"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.zip\CompressedFolder\ShellNew]
"Data"=hex:50,4b,05,06,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"ItemName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,7a,00,69,00,70,00,66,00,6c,00,64,00,72,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,\
  2d,00,31,00,30,00,31,00,39,00,34,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.zip\OpenWithProgids]
"CompressedFolder"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.zip\PersistentHandler]
@="{098f2470-bae0-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder]
@="Compressed (zipped) Folder"
"AppUserModelID"=hex(2):4d,00,69,00,63,00,72,00,6f,00,73,00,6f,00,66,00,74,00,\
  2e,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,2e,00,45,00,78,00,70,00,6c,\
  00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,00,00
"EditFlags"=dword:00200000
"FriendlyTypeName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,\
  00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,\
  32,00,5c,00,7a,00,69,00,70,00,66,00,6c,00,64,00,72,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\
  00,2c,00,2d,00,31,00,30,00,31,00,39,00,35,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\CLSID]
@="{E88DCCE0-B7B3-11d1-A9F0-00AA0060FA31}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,7a,00,69,00,\
  70,00,66,00,6c,00,64,00,72,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\shell\find]
"LegacyDisable"=""
"SuppressionPolicy"=dword:00000080

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\shell\find\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,45,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,\
  65,00,00,00
"DelegateExecute"="{a015411a-f97d-4ef3-8425-8a38d022aebc}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\shell\Open]
"MultiSelectModel"="Document"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\shell\Open\Command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,45,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,\
  65,00,20,00,2f,00,69,00,64,00,6c,00,69,00,73,00,74,00,2c,00,25,00,49,00,2c,\
  00,25,00,4c,00,00,00
"DelegateExecute"="{11dbb47c-a525-400b-9e80-a54615a090c0}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\{b8cdcb65-b1bf-4b42-9428-1dfdb7ee92af}]
@="Compressed (zipped) Folder Menu"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\ShellEx\DropHandler]
@="{ed9d80b9-d157-457b-9192-0e7280313bf0}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\ShellEx\StorageHandler]
@="{E88DCCE0-B7B3-11d1-A9F0-00AA0060FA31}"

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.zip]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.zip\CLSID]
@="{E88DCCE0-B7B3-11d1-A9F0-00AA0060FA31}"

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.zip]

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Roaming\OpenWith\FileExts\.zip]
```

You can also download the same code within a readily available `.reg` file from original source below...

(Source:  [Restore Default File Type Associations in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8703-restore-default-file-type-associations-windows-10-a.html))

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks for the link as well in case I run into other file extension associations that are messed up.

Comment: Always glad to help!